# nginx rewrite regex with multiple backreferences

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am new to Nginx and am trying to setup rewrite rules for my Nginx virtual hosts.

`/{firstname}-{lastname}.php` to be rewritten to `/Individual.php?firstname={firstname}&lastname={lastname}`

`/{firstname}-{lastname}-Info.php?Id=123` to be rewritten to `/Individual-Info.php?Id={id}`

That's the happy-case scenario. Sometimes, there might be a middle name as well e.g.

`{firstname}-{middle}-{lastname}.php` to be rewritten to `Individual.php?firstname={firstname}&middle={middle}&lastname={lastname}`

`/{firstname}-{middle}-{lastname}-Info.php?Id=123&otherparam={otherparam}` to be rewritten to `/Individual-Info.php?Id={id}&otherparam={otherparam}`

And sometimes, there might just be the last name

`{lasname}.php` to rewrite to `Individual.php?lastname={lastname}`

I have read the docs on the rewrite module, but I guess I am just struggling with the right regex, so this might be more of a regex question, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order the rewrites so that the more specific match occurs **before** the less specific match. Do `-Info` first, then three names, then two names, then one name.

The rewrites are ambiguous, and there is a risk of a redirection loop, particularly for *Mr Individual*. You should probably place the `rewrite` statements inside your **existing** `location ~ \.php$` block and use the `break` suffix. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite -Info\.php$ /Individual-Info.php break;
    rewrite ^/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?firstname=$1&middle=$2&lastname=$3 break;        
    rewrite ^/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?firstname=$1&lastname=$2 break;        
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?lastname=$1 break;        
    ...
}
```

---

In response to your comment, you can rewrite only `.php` URIs which do not already exist by using `try_files` with a named `location`.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    ...
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite -Info\.php$ /Individual-Info.php last;
    rewrite ^/(.*)-(.*)-(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?firstname=$1&middle=$2&lastname=$3 last;        
    rewrite ^/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?firstname=$1&lastname=$2 last;        
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.php$ /Individual.php?lastname=$1 last;        
    return 404;
}
```

Notice that you will need to use `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...break`. The `try_files` statement is added (or modified) within your **existing** `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll try that, will these rules also forward any query string in the URL ?

Comment: The default behaviour of `rewrite` is to append any existing query string **unless** the replacement value ends with a `?`

Comment: Is there a way that these rules execute only if the file does not already exist? @richard-smith

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I tried that but it seems it changes the URL... So if I have Someone-Info.php in the URL, then the URL becomes Individual-Info.php after this change....is that expected?

Comment: My bad, ignore my last comment...it is not changing the URL

Comment: could you help me with another similar question? thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417136/nginx-redirect-multiple-urls-with-map