# nginx redirect multiple URLs with map

Tags: regex, nginx

I am trying to redirect a bunch of old URLs into new URls with the map directive. I am able to do the simple ones but kinda stuck on the ones with query parameters.

I need to do this

```
/people.php?personid=20 -> /people/20
/events.php/eventid=20 -> /event/20
/info.php?name=john&age=20 -> /person/john/20
```

I've got a map directive

```
map $request_uri $redirected_uri {
~^people.php\?personid=(.*)^ /people/$1?;
}
```

But doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My server block has this code

```
if ($redirected_uri) {
   rewrite  ^ $redirected_uri permanent;
}
```

Also, I am trying to do the following as well
rewrite /people/20 back to people.php?personId=20
So, for that, I have this

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
default 0
~^/people/(.*) /people.php?personId=$1;
}
```

and then in server block

```
if ($new_uri) {
rewrite ^ $new_uri last; // this doesn't work, throws 404
}
```

Comment: How do you use this `map` substitution inside your `server` block?

Comment: @IvanShatsky just added that code to the question

Comment: You don't need to use `map` for the second part. Try: `rewrite ^/people/(.*)$ /people.php?personId=$1 last;`

Comment: @RichardSmith I am using map because there are over 50 URLs like this.

Comment: Well, you cannot use `$1` (see my answer below) and you need to place the `if` block inside the `location /` block to avoid a redirection loop.

Comment: So, what do you suggest for rewriting 50+ URLs - The idea is that the first map is for search engine URLs redirecting to new URLs and then the second map is for actually processing those new URLs

Comment: also, there won't be a redirect loop as the first map does a 301 redirect and the second one does a rewrite, I am not seeing a redirection loop here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric capture goes out of scope as soon as another regular expression is evaluated, so the `rewrite` statement itself wipes the value of `$1` from the previous `map` statement.

You could use a `return` statement instead:

```
if ($redirected_uri) {
    return 301 $redirected_uri;
}
```

Or better still, use a named capture in the `map`:

```
map $request_uri $redirected_uri {
~^/people\.php\?personid=(?<personid>.*)$ /people/$personid;
}
```

Note also that Nginx URIs begin with a leading `/`, you had an unescaped `.`, and the correct anchor for the end of a regular expression is `$`.

Comment: that works, thanks! I also need to do the reverse, please see the modified question. can you help with that?

Comment: Is there anyway to rename the parameters

e.g. ~^/people\.php\?personid=(?<personid>.*)$ /people?id=$personid

this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: is it possible to do multiple named captures (like in my 3rd URL in the question)

Comment: Yes, for example: `~^/info\.php\?name=(?<name>[^&]+)&age=(?<age>\d+) /person/$name/$age;`

Comment: is there a way to make it so the order of the query parameters doesn't matter? e.g. age could be before the name in the above example.

Comment: The simplest solution is to add another regular expression to the map.

Comment: there can be many variations so adding regex for every case might be too much work...is there a way to parse the URL params regardless of which order they are in?

Comment: Nginx has already assigned the parameters to `$arg_` variables. Can you structure a solution around that?

Answer (score 0):

The common way to solve this looks something like this:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default                          0;
    ~^/people.php\?personid=(\d+)^    /people/$1;
    ...
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) {
        set $args '';
        return 301 $redirect;
    }
```

I have limited the capture group after `personid=` to digits: `\d+`

Comment: yeah it seems to send the querystring as well - how do I remove it? I have it like this

```
if ($redirected_uri) {
   rewrite  ^ $redirected_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: /people.php?personid=20 gets changed to /people/20?personid=20 - I don't want the query string to be added.

Comment: doesn/t seem to help. Isn't there something else where if I add a ? at the end, Nginx won't add querystring...even that doesn't seem to work for me.